# PostgreSQL docker container on Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker, permissions

I've been trying to run a PostgresSQL Docker container on my Windows machine and mounting the data volume, using the following command:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -it --volume c:\Users\me\Desktop\pg\data\:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:latest -e POSTGRES_USER=user POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
```

However I keep getting a list of permission denied errors when the container tries to spin up:

```
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_log’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_logical/mappings’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_logical/snapshots’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_logical’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_multixact/members/0000’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_multixact/members’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_multixact/offsets/0000’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_multixact/offsets’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_multixact’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_notify/0000’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_notify’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_replslot’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_serial’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_snapshots’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_stat’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_stat_tmp/db_0.stat’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_stat_tmp/db_16395.stat’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_stat_tmp/global.stat’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_stat_tmp’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_subtrans/0000’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_subtrans’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_tblspc’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_twophase’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/PG_VERSION’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_xlog/00000001000000000000000A’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_xlog/00000001000000000000000B’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_xlog/archive_status’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_xlog’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.auto.conf’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/postmaster.opts’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data/postmaster.pid’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/lib/postgresql/data’: Permission denied
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is known limitation in Docker for Windows. The Linux <-> Windows filesystem mapping semantics from your Windows dir to the Linux dir are imperfect because the mount is done with CIFS/SMB. One of the things that won't work is `chown` (changing the owner) because that cannot be mapped to your Windows filesystem.

You should probably use a named volume instead. This forum post has details: https://forums.docker.com/t/data-directory-var-lib-postgresql-data-pgdata-has-wrong-ownership/17963/24?u=friism

Comment: @friism, I've hit this issue and have followed your advice to use a named volume. Do you know of any way to get the data from the named volume onto my Windows host (even just a one-time copy would be helpful)?

Comment: I ended up having to do a pg_dump from the original host followed by an import.

ssh user@remote-host -C "pg_dump -O -x -U your-db-username db-name" >> /your/desired/path/client_dump.sql

followed by 

/path/to/psql -f client_dump.sql -U username -h yourhost -p 5432 -d db-name

I would take a long look at the documentation on the Postgres website (which is frankly excellent)

Answer (score 2):

I posted a partial solution to one of the related git issue links.
A partial workaround can be done by using Postgres *tablespaces* to store the database object files on the windows host system. It is not a perfect solution because the core data directory (represented by `PGDATA`) still resides on the LinuxVM. But at least you can manage subsequent database creation and file storage on the Windows host and outside the Linux VM.

```
docker run --rm --name mypostgres
           -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pwd
           -d -p 5432:5432 
           -v /var/lib/docker/basedata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
           -v d:/data/largedb:/mnt/largedb
           postgres
```

This sets the default data storage to a (persistent) directory on the Linux VM (`/var/lib/docker/basedata`).
It also tells docker to mount your windows `D:\data\largedb` as a volume that is visible to the Postgres container as `/mnt/largedb`. (The windows directory need not exist yet.)
Log into postgres and using psql or whatever tool, execute the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE winhoststorage LOCATION '/mnt/largedb';
CREATE DATABASE "my_large_db" WITH TABLESPACE = "winhoststorage";
```

Go ahead and create tables and data in `my_large_db`. Stop the containter. Navigate to `D:\data\largedb` in Windows Explorer and you will see data files. Restart the container and you will see the data from the previous session.

(Note: Docker Desktop for Windows (2.2) on Win 10 which uses the DockerDesktopVM and not MobyLinux or docker-machine.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using docker with hyper-v or docker-toolbox? Because in my experience, I used only docker-toolbox (it uses docker-machine), and to map a volume successfully using --volume or -v (is the same) you should put this nomenclature for the Win path:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -it -v /c/Users/me/Desktop/pg/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:latest -e POSTGRES_USER=user POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
```

Not sure if it can help. Maybe your problem is because of the path for the mapped volume. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, I think I can't help. Anyway try my solution to check if on docker-hyperv the volume mapping is done in the same way.

Comment: Do you have a custom Dockerfile or just `docker run` command downloading the standard postgresql image? Because if is a custom Dockerfile maybe you have a problem of permission inside your container. If is the standard image, maybe postgresql staff failed in something with their last image... try different tag. Instead of latest, try posgres:9.2 for example

Comment: I'm pulling from docker:latest. I'll try a different tag and follow up with the results. Appreciate the feedback!